# Calculating the area of a triplet of circles.

Tags: geometry, contest-math, circles, area

I have an image of the problem which is quite self-explanatory. [image]

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't see a way that doesn't take some work. Draw lines to make a few triangles and sectors, and see if you can wiggle your way from area calculation to area calculation to finally arrive at an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\pi x=$ area of $3$ equal pieces. So area of one piece$=\pi x/3$.

Now notice that

area of one piece= Area of a sector of a circle which has a central angle of $\pi /3$ rad$= r^2 \pi/6$.